# Can I upload only co-assemblies to ENA, using existing ENA samples?

Tags: public-databases

Lets say I am using reads downloaded from [ENA](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/PRJEB6603), assembling them and doing further downstream analyses. Would it be possible to then upload the results of the co-assemblies and other analyses back to ENA, and just linking them up with the reads I originally downloaded, without having to re-upload the original reads?